# Can't create Robot Framework API automation test using API key in the header

Tags: robotframework, web-api-testing

I create an API automation test for POST requests. I use the following libraries: RequestLibrary and HttpLibrary.HTTP.

I have a JSON object for the request body. My header contains of content type: `application/json` and API Key. How to send api key in robot framework?

```
***Settings***                  
Library             RequestsLibrary
Library             HttpLibrary.HTTP            


***Variables***
${url}              https://blabla/api/login            
${email}            blabla
${password}         blabla


***Test Cases***
API Login Email
    ${apikey}=    Set Variable    wQ0f7FgE9wLhq

    ${body}=    catenate    {"email_or_phone":${email},"password":${password}}
       &{header}=      Create Dictionary       Content-Type=application/json

       CreateSession        login       ${url}      ${header}    auth=${apikey}       verify=True
       ${resp}=    Post Request    login    api/login    data=${body}    headers=${header}
       Should Be Equal As Strings   ${resp.status_code} 200
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code as a reproducible example.

Comment: if possible you should share your code here.

Comment: The error 404 is resource/page not found. Check the URL you're sending the request to, the server is returning to you there's no service bound to that location (e.g. you might have mistyped it).